# A field Isomorphism $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: group-isomorphism

Any suggestions for a field Isomorphism $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ other than the identity map?

Comment: Complex conjugation?

Comment: or of [Field isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ onto itself](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/705127). Seriously, try searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the map $\phi:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ given by $\phi(z) = \overline{z}$? It satisfies $\phi(0) = 0$, $\phi(1) = 1$, $\phi(z_1+z_2) = \phi(z_1)+\phi(z_2)$ and $\phi(z_1z_2) = \phi(z_1)\phi(z_2)$.

Answer (score 7):

Complex field automorphisms other than the identity and the complex conjugation do exist, and are called "wild". They are described in the expository paper by Paul B. Yale, [Automorphisms of the complex numbers](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/PaulBYale.pdf), Math. Mag. 39 (1966), 135-141.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Define $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ by $f(z) = \overline {z} $.

Answer (score 2):

The only *continuous* automorphisms of $\mathbf C$ are the identity map and conjugation.

However, using the axiom of choice, it can be shown there is a infinity of non-continuous field automorphisms of $\mathbf C$. You can look at [this paper](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/PaulBYale.pdf).